# USB drivers fall under which category of drivers? character drivers or block drivers?

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver, block-device

I am trying to implement USB drivers in Linux. Before that, I want to know whether USB drivers are character drivers or block drivers? or is it a separate category?

Comment: Your question is poorly phrased and/or reflects weak understanding of USB.  USB is a bus.  By *"USB drivers"* are you referring to the (platform) drivers for USB host or gadget controllers?  Or are you referring drivers for the devices that can be attached to a host through USB, e.g. a USB flash drive (a block device) or serial port adapter (a char device) or a WiFi adapter (a network device)?

Comment: Well, this might help: http://free-electrons.com/doc/linux-usb.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are both character and block USB drivers:

- `cdc-acm` is a character driver (for USB CDC serial ports).
- `usb-storage` is a block device driver (USB mass storage).

You could omit developing a kernel level USB driver by using [LibUSB](http://www.libusb.org/) in your application.

Comment: The answer is misleading and/or incomplete.  What about a network adapter?